# Solve for the Walrasian demand, Utility of three variables, and Convexity of Preferences?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, consumer-theory, walrasian

I am given $U(x,y,z) = x^\frac{2}{3}y^\frac{1}{3} + z$. I am asked to solve the following:

(i) Prove the convexity of these preferences (convex, strictly convex or neither?)
(ii) Solve for the Walrasian Demand?

For part 1, I calculated the determinant of the bordered hessian matrix and got  $\frac{320}{81}*\frac{1}{x^\frac{2}{3}y^\frac{4}{3}}$. Here I concluded that if x and y are greater than zero (This was not given to me I assumed this), then determinant is greater than zero so $U$ must be quasi-concave and hence preferences are convex. Is this correct?

For part 2, I considered three cases. 

Case 1: when $z = 0$ and $x,y > 0$. This was just the Walrasian for the standard Cobb Douglas we are left with.

Case 2: when $x$ or $y = 0$ and $z > 0$. All wealth is spent on z as well. 

Case 3:  $x,y,z > 0$. This I was unable to compute and did not know how to proceed.

Note: Budget constraint is standard $P_1X+P_2Y+P_3Z = W$

For Case 3: I set up Lagrangian and used Kuhn Tucker Conditions:

1. $\frac{2}{3}$*$(\frac{y}{x})^{\frac{1}{3}} - \lambda P_1 \le 0$
2. $\frac{1}{3}$*$(\frac{x}{y})^{\frac{2}{3}} - \lambda P_2 \le 0$
3. $1 - \lambda P_3 \le 0$
4. $x[\frac{2}{3}$*$(\frac{y}{x})^{\frac{1}{3}} - \lambda P_1] = 0$
5. $y[\frac{1}{3}$*$(\frac{x}{y})^{\frac{2}{3}} - \lambda P_2] = 0$
6. $z[1 - \lambda P_3] = 0$
7. $W - P_1X - P_2Y - P_3Z \ge 0 $
8. $\lambda [W - P_1X - P_2Y - P_3Z] = 0$

Imposing $x, y, z > 0$ and Walras's law, I know that I can equate 1, 2, 3, and 7 to zero. Essentially I end up with an equation which says that at optimal Marginal Utility to Price Ratio of each good is same.

After simplifying by equating $\lambda$, I get this from 1, 2:

$\frac{x}{P_2} = \frac{2y}{P_1}$. 
My problem is that I can't solve for $z$ as I can't get my budget constraint all in terms of one variable.

Comment: In the part 2 I think you may need to look in cases when the price is different, because the good $z$ is like a substitute of the combination of $x & y$ so if the price of $z$ is much higher than the prices for the combination $x & y$ the consumer will consume only $x & y$ solving the demand as a standard coub douglas, while if the price of $z$ is much lower than the prices for the combination $x & y$ the consumer will consume only $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (i), in complete rigor, you should also check [the determinants of all the leading principal minors of the bordered Hessian and make sure that they have alternating signs](https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/qcc/t#d:borderedHessian). Your final conclusion looks correct though.

For part (ii), recall that Walrasian demand is the solution to utility maximization subject to budget constraint. So you should setup a Lagrangian, derive the [Kuhn-Tucker conditions](https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/ktc/t), and then solve for $x,y,z$ as functions of the prices and income. These will be the Walrasian demands.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my question with the Kuhn Tucker conditions. Because z, disappears I am unable to isolate x, y, and z just in terms of prices and wealth, which is what the Walrasian correspondence demands.

Comment: @Kinno: You can usually recover $z$ from the budget constraint after solving for $x$ and $y$. You should probably start from your condition $3$, and use the fact/assumption that $p_1,p_2,p_3>0$ to deduce that $\lambda>0$, which in turn will give you strict equality in condition $7$, and go from there.

Comment: @Kinno: Also, the MU-to-Price Ratio gives you a relation between $x$ and $y$, e.g. $x=2yp_2/p_1$. Plug this into either $1$ or $2$ for $x$, and you'll get $y$ as an expression of prices and $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks I think I get it now.

Comment: When all are positive x,y,z>0 there is an infinity of solutions. This only happens at particular prices. Walras demand is in this knife-edge case not strictly speaking a function of price and income as suggested by @Herr K.

Comment: @JesperHybel: Yes you're right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

$u(x,y,z)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}}+z$ is the sum of two concave functions: $u_1(x,y,z)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $u_2(x,y,z)=z$, and therefore, it is concave. Since $u$ is concave, it is also quasi-concave. Preferences represented by $u$ are, therefore, convex. However, these preferences are not strictly convex. To show this, consider $(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(2,2,0)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)=(0,0,2)$, and $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$. Clearly,
$u(\lambda (x_1,y_1,z_1) + (1-\lambda)(x_2,y_2,z_2))=u(1,1,1)=2=u(2,2,0)=u(0,0,2)=\min(u(x_1,y_1,z_1),u(x_2,y_2,z_2))$

Demand can be obtained by solving this problem:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x,y,z} & \ x^{\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}}+z \\ \text{s.t. } & p_Xx+p_Yy+p_Zz\leq M \\ \text{and } & x\geq 0, \ y\geq 0, \ z \geq 0\end{eqnarray*}
where $p_X>0, p_Y>0, p_Z>0, M\geq 0$

and we get the demand as

$(x^d,y^d,z^d)(p_X,p_Y,p_Z,M)\in\begin{cases} \left\{\left(\dfrac{2M}{3p_X},\dfrac{M}{3p_Y},0\right)\right\} &\text{if } \frac{3p_X^{\frac{2}{3}}p_Y^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2^{\frac{2}{3}}}<p_Z \\ \left\{\left(0,0,\dfrac{M}{p_Z}\right)\right\} & \text{if } \frac{3p_X^{\frac{2}{3}}p_Y^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2^{\frac{2}{3}}}>p_Z \\ \left\{\left(\dfrac{2\alpha M}{3p_X},\dfrac{\alpha M}{3p_Y},\dfrac{(1-\alpha)M}{p_Z}\right)|0\leq\alpha\leq 1\right\}&\text{if } \frac{3p_X^{\frac{2}{3}}p_Y^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2^{\frac{2}{3}}}=p_Z\end{cases}$

Note: Approach I have used to find the demand here is same as the one I have used here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/51562/11824